# Civi contribution details correct but why does Paypal log show wrong name?

Tags: civimember, paypal, logs

So, person 1 pays membership fee using credit card via Paypal standard.  Transaction goes through fine. Membership record is updated correctly

On the Paypal log however the payment show as for person 2; but when you drill down it then shows it correctly for person 1.  In Civi, Person 1 and Person 2 have a relationship

Out of a few hundred recent payments I can see 2 that this has occurred for: its not a show stopper but Im curious about why?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Paypal log".  Is this a log in PayPal, or in CiviCRM?  If in CiviCRM, can you send a screenshot that includes the URL so we can see?

Comment: no, its the log in PayPal:  something like  "Payment received from Person 2" when you click on it it then shows full details something like: $100 received from Person 1  In Civi it shows correctly ie a membership is updated for Person 1 and nothing for Person 2 .. I get that this is not strictly a Civi issue,, but PayPal is getting its info from somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Is there any chance that Person 1 may have used a PayPal account or credit card belonging to Person 2?  We'll frequently see payments that have different names: if I pay with your card, from PayPal's perspective, you've made the payment even though I've entered my name as the contact in CiviCRM.

Comment: Andrew, Person 1 says not but its I suppose always possible that in the past there might have been: anyway,, not really worth spending too much time worrying about.. I was just curious as to how it might have happened.  thanks for your input